# Oracle - not a valid month

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datetime

I get a timestamp from Facebook in the below code

```
cust_updated_time = obj["updated_time"].ToString();//2013-08-01T02:55:31+0000
abccusttime = cust_updated_time.Substring(0, cust_updated_time.ToString().Length - 3);//2013-08-01T02:55:31+0
```

Here I'm trying to insert into Oracle table

```
to_date('" + abccusttime + "', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

but I get an error "not a valid month"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh... Your string has a completely different format than the one you specify as the second parameter of `to_date`. Adjust the specified format to the actual format of your string.

Comment: You receive `yyyy-MM-dd` but are reading `MM-dd-yyyy` instead. Obviously, `to_date` will tell you that `13` is not a valid month.

Comment: @Nolonar - or `20`, as the case may be... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is your date:

```
2013-08-01T02:55:31+0
```

It should look like this:

```
2013-08-01 02:55:31
```

Than you can use TO_DATE function (with correct mask format):

```
to_date('" + abccusttime + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to map:

```
2013-08-01T02:55:31+0
```

with the format:

```
mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss
```

it's not going to work simply because your date components are in the wrong place. It's expecting a two-digit month at the start but you're giving it the century of `20`, which is most definitely not a valid month.

You need to either change your data or your mapping so that they match.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to parameterize your query, but in this case you've got your time format wrong. To match;

```
2013-08-01T02:55:31+0000
```

you need a format like;

```
yyyy-MM-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"+0000"
```

or, if you want the preprocessed format with a single zero;

```
yyyy-MM-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"+0"
```

Sample;

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2013-08-01T02:55:31+0000', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"+0000"') FROM DUAL;

> August, 01 2013 02:55:31+0000
```

[Oracle date format reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

You could also match/process the time zone information, but since it's not clear what result you'd like if it were set, I left it out (`TZH` and `TZM` will help there)

[A rather trivial SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15813).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle date format you want is mm-dd-yyyy, but the facebook timestamp is yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this instead;

```
 to_date(:abccusttime, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Then set a parameter for abbcusttime, also don't use apostrophes (') when adding parameters, it doesn't like that :)

```
OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(":abccusttime", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = abccusttime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use parameters

```
  DateTime updatedtime = obj["updated_time"] as DateTime;

  var statement = "..... where Updated_time > :updatedtime";

    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(statement, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":updatedtime", updatedtime );
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```